# AndEngine Texture Packer Error

Tags: android, andengine

I cant even get the example working for this, it throws the following error

02-04 19:22:05.617: E/AndroidRuntime(2548): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Supplied pTextureAtlasSource must not exceed bounds of Texture.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what it mean? This is just the example program that I installed

Answer (score 2):

Ok, anyone that has this issue...

First of all that error was not correct, I seemed to have an older version of the AndEngine that was throwing that error. Also the example that is provided is flawed

Although it spcifies the base folder is "gfx" this doesnt apply for TexturePacket Textures therefore the path for the object should be "gfx/spritesheet/". I discovered this after it started to throw a null pointer exception after updating the engine